# What weapons are "precision weapons"?

Tags: halo-reach

Several of the daily challenges have asked for precision weapon kills. What weapons apply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Focus Rifle](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Type-52_Special_Applications_Rifle)

Race: Covenant
Damage Per Hit: Medium-High
Magazine Size: 100 Battery Units
Fire Mode: Continuous
Rate of Fire: Continuous
Muzzle Velocity: Very Fast
Range:  Long

### [Needle Rifle](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Type-31_Rifle)

Race: Covenant
Damage Per Hit: Medium
Magazine Size: 21 Rounds
Fire Mode: Automatic
Rate of Fire: 150 rpm
Range:  Medium to Long

### [Designated Marksman Rifle (DMR)](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/M392_Designated_Marksman_Rifle)

Race: Human
Damage Per Hit: Medium - High
Magazine Size: 15 Rounds
Maximum Ammunition: 60 rounds
Fire Mode: Semi-Automatic
Rate of Fire: 150 rpm
Range:  Medium to Long

### [Sniper Rifle](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Sniper_Rifle_System_99_Anti-Mat%C3%A9riel)

Race: Human
Damage Per Hit: Very high
Magazine Size: 4 Rounds
Maximum Ammunition: 24 rounds
Fire Mode: Semi-Automatic
Rate of Fire: Low
Range:  Very Long

---

For clarification on fire modes:

- Continuous fire mode: hold down trigger and will fire as a steady beam until released
- Automatic: hold down trigger and will continue fire shots until release
- Semi-Automatic: must release trigger before firing enough shot

Comment: Sniper rifle should be human, no? And the magazine size is on the wrong line.

Comment: The sniper rifle is a human weapon. *EDIT* nvm, Rapida got to it first.

Comment: Also, I am curious about your choices for fire mode. The needle rifle is technically fully automatic (you can hold the trigger down and fire continuously). The DMR and sniper rifle are both semi-automatic and are fired the same way (you must release the trigger), so I don't know what you mean by "select-fire".

Comment: Why is Needle Rifle damage only Medium and DMR Medium-High? They are both the same - 4 headshots to kill from fully shielded, 1 headshot to kill for unshielded and 3 body shots to kill from unshielded

Answer (score 3):

The precision weapons are DMR, sniper rifle, and needle rifle. The pistol is not a precision weapon (it is a small arms weapon).